# SAS 32 Character column name issue

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to comply with the 32 character limit restriction on columns by renaming them as they come in from their source.  The issue is that by using the datastep (below) I get a "ERROR 23-322: Variable name is longer than 32 characters" error.

Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
    data mydata;
    set mydata;
        rename Thisisthelongcolumnnamefromthesourcetable = ShorterName;
    run;
```

I have heard that using ds2 my remedy the issue, but every attempt I made with ds2 gave me similar errors.  Since I don't have direct control over the source data, is there a workaround for this limitation?

Also, it seems that SAS auto truncates the name of the column, however the "label name" remains the actual length.  Is there a way to change the Column name by referencing it's label name?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: No, but you can get the name from SASHELP.VCOLUMN which has metadata including the labels, variable types and variable names.  What is your original source data type?

Comment: The source is a varchar(50) from a sql table

Comment: Can you connect to the source via SQL Pass Through, that's the best bet to get it renamed appropriately.

Comment: It's actually the result of a stored procedure, I'm not sure how to rename the columns as they come in that way

Comment: Suggest you show your PROC DS2 code. Won’t work in data step.

Answer (score 1):

An 'inline macro' can be written to generate the rename option for you. An 'inline macro' is one that does not emit SAS code that causes a step boundary to be executed -- the macro will perform processing and emit a SAS code snippet that can be utilized as part of other SAS statements.

Consider a macro with signature

```
%renameByLabel(data=, byvarname=allow, rename=(label-1=newname-1 label-2=newname-2)).
```

The macro will open the data set, examine each variable's name and label and attempt to match them to one of the `label=name` pairs listed in the `rename=` parameter.

The use of such a macro could be used to handled the necessary rename actions for this code

```
data have;
  x12345=1;            label x12345="This is x";
  ___y__scrap = "ABC"; label ___y__scrap="This is y";
  ageold = 7;          label ageold="Old age";
run;

data want;
  set have (%renameByLabel(data=have,rename=("This is x"=x "This is y"=y ageold=age)));
run;
```

Macro does not have access to the current executor tokenization stream and thus can not know the data set the current statement will be processing.  The macro requires the data set to process to be explicitly stated with `data=` (even when the inline invocation result is part of a `set` statement)

**Sample macro**

```
%macro renameByLabel(data=, byvarname=allow, rename=) / parmbuff;

  %local allow ds nvar ri i rename varlabel varname L pair lhs rhs result pairename;
  %let allow = %upcase(%superq(byvarname));

  %let ds = %sysfunc(open(&data));
  %if &ds %then %do;

    %if %index(&ds,%str(%()) %then 
      %put WARNING: &SYSMACRONAME does not like KEEP= or DROP= options;

    %let nvar = %sysfunc(attrn(&ds, nvar));

    %let L = %length(%superq(rename));
    %if "%substr(%superq(rename),&L,1)" = ")" %then %let rename=%substr(%superq(rename),1,%eval(&L-1));

    %let L = %length(%superq(rename));
    %if "%substr(%superq(rename),1,1)" = "(" %then %let rename=%substr(%superq(rename),2,%eval(&L-1));

    %let L = %length(&rename);
    %do ri = 1 %to &L;
      %let pair = %scan(%superq(rename),&ri,%str( ),Q);

      %if %length (&pair) %then %do;

        %let lhs = %scan(%superq(pair),1,=,Q);
        %let rhs = %scan(%superq(pair),2,=,Q);
        %let pairename =;

        %do i = 1 %to &nvar;
          %let varname = %sysfunc(varname(&ds,&i));
          %let varlabel = %sysfunc(varlabel(&ds,&i));

          %if %superq(varlabel) = %superq(lhs) or
             "%superq(varlabel)" = %superq(lhs) 
          %then %do;
            %let pairename = &varname=&rhs;
            %let i = &nvar;
          %end;

          %if &allow=ALLOW %then %do;
            %if &varname = %superq(lhs) or
               "&varname" = %superq(lhs)
            %then %do;
              %let pairename = &varname=&rhs;
            %end;
          %end;
        %end;

        %let result = &result &pairename;

      %end;
      %else
        %let ri = &L;

    %end;

    %let ds = %sysfunc(close(&ds));

    %* emit the generated rename option in-line;
    rename=(&result)
    %put NOTE: Generated rename option is %superq(result);
  %end;
  %else
    %put ERROR: Could not open data=%superq(data);

%mend;
```

**Macro test**

```
* test 1;
%put %renameByLabel (data=sashelp.class, varname=Allow, rename=("Name"=NewName Age=NewAge));

* ===log===;
* NOTE: Generated rename option is rename=(Name=NewName Age=NewAge);

* test 2;
data have;
  x12345=1; label x12345="This is x";
  ___y__scrap = "ABC"; label ___y__scrap="This is y";
  ageold = 7; label ageold="Old age";
run;

data want;
  set have (%renameByLabel(data=have,rename=("This is x"=x "This is y"=y ageold=age)));
run;

* ===log===;
* NOTE: Generated rename option is rename=(x12345=x ___y__scrap=y ageold=age)
```

**Aside**

Small changes would be needed to have the macro emit just the rename pairs, so it could be used as part of a data set `rename=()` option, or as part of `rename` statement.

You could rewrite the macro as a Proc DS2 function, say `myRenameByLabel` and invoke the function with `%sysfunc(myRenameByLabel(…))`.  Sometimes it is easier to deal with unusual quoting and unquoting situations in DS2 statements.

Comment: Interesting comment about DS2. Do you have papers or other examples of where DS2 functions make a macro developer’s life easier? I haven’t played with DS2 much, but that could be motivation for me.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'm going to test this now!

Comment: If you find it works, great! However if you are doing a lot of importations, and find the labels or variable names varying slightly, you can modify the macro to utilize a data set of 'known' or 'desired' *inbound mappings*, i.e. a table of `to_var`, `from_var`, `from_label`.  Then you can have the macro read from the mappings table instead of specifying the rename pairs, and add new rows as new variables or variations of variables are encountered.  The mappings table is often called a 'control table'

Comment: Thank you Richard for the detailed example and explanation.  Do you also have an example of what this would look like in DS2 as well? For my own education?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to utilize this during a PROC SQL step? I encounter the issue after that step, as SAS auto-truncates two columns to the same name, and only one shows up in the data set.  Example: Thisreallylongcolumnname1 and Thisreallylongcolumnname2 truncates to Thisreallylongcol, as only one column, losing the data in the 2nd column

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
data mydata;
set mydata (rename=(Thisisthelongcolumnnamefromthesourcetable = ShorterName));   
run;
```

SAS is doing the variable naming in the SET statement. Since you were not trying the RENAME function until after the SET statement had completed, it was already too late. Doing the RENAME as a SET statement option, as shown above, renames the variable before it is read in by SET.